# Iterate through object and append new data with forEach

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop, for-loop, iteration

I'm creating a navbar and trying to do it with object oriented programming in mind.

On my navbar I got social icons that you can click on to connect with me. The idéa is to only add new keys and values in my object to add a new social icon in the future.

For each key and value of navbar.socialLinks I want to append my html with different imgSrc and link values on each new icon that appends. Is there a smart way to do it?

Thank you in advance.

```
const navbar = {
"socialLinks": {
    github: {
        imgSrc: "assets/images/github_logo.png" , 
        link:   "https://www.github.com"
    },
    line: {
        imgSrc: "assets/images/line_logo.png" , 
        link:   ""
    },
    linkedin: {
        imgSrc: "assets/images/linkedin_logo.png", 
        link:   "https://www.linkedin.com"
    },
    showLinks: function() {

        let social = Object.values(navbar.socialLinks)
        let imgSrc = [];
        let socialLinks = [];

        for(let values of social) {
            imgSrc.push(values.imgSrc);
            socialLinks.push(values.link);
        }

        imgSrc.pop(); // Remove the function from the Arrays
        socialLinks.pop();

        imgSrc.forEach(function() {

            $('.social-icons').append
            
            (`
            <div class="item-social">
                <a href="${socialLinks[0]}" target="_rel">
                <img src="${imgSrc[0]}" alt="">
                </a>
                <div class="item-social-text">
                <div class="underscore"></div>
                <span class="open">Open</span>
            </div>
            `)
        })

        console.log(imgSrc);
        console.log(socialLinks);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some remarks:

- As you don't use the keys of `socialLinks`, and order is important, it makes more sense to define it as an array of objects.
- The `pop` action you do to remove the function from the arrays, is not that nice. It is better to avoid that from happening in the first place: keep that function separate from the data.
- Don't push the links and images to separate arrays. You should work with the data structure that you already have. There is no need to convert it
- As you use jQuery, use it also for generating the DOM content.
- I am not convinced you want to have an "Open" action for the line-element. Use a condition to have that `span` element included or not. You may want to do the same for some other content that should only be included when the object is not representing a divisor-line.

Here is how I would code it:

```
const navbar = {
    socialLinks: [{
        imgSrc: "assets/images/github_logo.png" , 
        link:   "https://www.github.com"
    }, {
        imgSrc: "assets/images/line_logo.png" , 
        link:   ""
    }, {
        imgSrc: "assets/images/linkedin_logo.png", 
        link:   "https://www.linkedin.com"
    }],
    showLinks() {
        $('.social-icons').append(this.socialLinks.map(({imgSrc, link}) =>
            $("<div>").addClass("item-social").append(
                $("<a>", {href: link, target: "_rel"}).append(
                    $("<img>", {src: imgSrc, alt: ""}),
                ),
                $("<div>").addClass("item-social-text"),
                $("<div>").addClass("underscore"),
                link && $("<span>").addClass("open").text("Open")
            )
        ));
    }
}
navbar.showLinks();
```

Answer (score 0):

Objects are not iterable so you cannot use forEach directly, but you can use `Object.keys()` to get array of keys and then use these keys to modify the object values:

```
 Object.keys(navbar.socialLinks).forEach(key => {
     navbar.socialLinks[key].imgSrc = 'new image src here';
     navbar.socialLinks[keys].link = 'new link here'
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
const navbar = {
  socialLinks: {
    github: {
      imgSrc: "assets/images/github_logo.png",
      link: "https://www.github.com"
    },
    line: {
      imgSrc: "assets/images/line_logo.png",
      link: ""
    },
    linkedin: {
      imgSrc: "assets/images/linkedin_logo.png",
      link: "https://www.linkedin.com"
    }
  },
  showLinks: () => {
    let social = Object.values(navbar.socialLinks);
    for (let value of social) {
      $(".social-icons").append(`
              <div class="item-social">
                  <a href="${value.link}" target="_rel">
                  <img src="${value.imgSrc}" alt="">
                  </a>
                  <div class="item-social-text">
                  <div class="underscore"></div>
                  <span class="open">Open</span>
              </div>
            `);
    }
  }
};
```

First I would sepparate the showLinks method from the values. Then there is no need to save imgSrc and link in sepparate lists, just use that object directly (if you add some more properties to an object you don't need to create a new array and this is more maintainable).